# Discrete Math Complement Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I have never been good with proofs and its especially harder when the math is discrete. I have no idea on how to do this proof.

Show that if S1 ⊆ S2, then S¯2⊆S¯1 (the complement of S2 is the subset of the complement of S1)

Comment: If $x\not\in S_2$ then, since $S_1\subset S_2$,...

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction. Let $x$ be a point in $S'_2$.
If it is not in $S'_1$, then it must be in $S_1$ and therefore in $S_2$. But $x$ cannot be in both $S_2$ and $S'_2$.

Note:  I am using ' to denote complement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand how to do it now. The answer is simple but I never know how to start it.